# Gradle properties not visible inside extension container closure

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write this custom plugin for Gradle but I'm stuck in properly passing parameters to the plugin.

inside the plugin I'm creating an extension like following:

```
@Override void apply(final Project p) {
    p.extensions.create('myPlugin', MyPluginData.class)
```

then inside `MyPluginData` I'm handling `def propertyMissing(String name, value)` to receive the customer parameters I expect.

And finally inside the client application `build.gradle` I'm trying to configure the data:

```
println("From root value is " + SOME_VALUE)

myPlugin {
    println("From plugin value is " + SOME_VALUE)
    println("But from plugin 'findProperty' value is " + findProperty("SOME_VALUE"))
    clientDataSet = {
        data_1 = SOME_VALUE
        data_2 = findProperty("SOME_VALUE")
        data_3 = "this is a string"
```

SOME_VALUE is defined on my project `gradle.properties`, and I got the following log during build:

> From root value is correct value from properties
>   From plugin value is null
>   But from plugin 'findProperty' value is correct value from properties

and then of course, while receiving `data_1` SOME_VALUE is null, `data_2` have the correct value and data 3 is the hard-coded string I passed.

---

My question:

What am I doing wrong or which configuration is missing on my plugin, so that the client application can directly reference properties from their `gradle.properties` files?

---

**Edit:** as requested on the comments

`MyPluginData` is simply `extends HashMap<String, MyPluginDataSet>` and `MyPluginDataSet` is just a few strings.

So inside `propertyMissing` I'm simply adding the property name to the map, and creating the `MyPluginDataSet` with the strings, (that later is used to generate custom tasks).

The missing property function:

```
def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
    // Create the new data set and add to the map
    def data = new MyPluginDataSet()
    put(name, data)

    // setup and execute the client closure to configure the data
    def closure = value as Closure
    closure.delegate = data
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure.run()
}
```

Comment: can you provide some more code from your MyPluginData extension class? especially your custom methods *propertyMissing* implementation, and *clientDataSet* definition ?

Comment: hi @M.Ricciuti I just edited the question with the complete propertyMissing.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but no luck, SOME_VALUE always has a value

Comment: I reproduce the issue  when I make MyPluginData  inherit from HashMap<String, MyPluginDataSet> : I guess this is why  the delegate/property resolution not working when you try to access "SOME_VALUE" from within 'myPlugin' closure : Gradle (Groovy) will try to get value for this property from the inherited map and will not try to search in other scopes (see : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html)

Comment: Extending `HashMap` is not a good practice in my opinion, `myPlugin`should hold a  `HashMap` instance and not be one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making `MyPluginData` inherit from `Map<>`, I think you somehow "break" the property resolution process  ( see [ExtensionAware](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html)) and Gradle will not try to search for "SOME_VALUE" property in the different scopes (so it will not find this property from gradle properties extension)

Maybe you can try to simplify you `MyPluginData` class by storing an internal map instead of inheriting from Map ?  something like that:

```
class MyPluginData {
    Map<String, MyPluginDataSet> internalMap = new HashMap<>()

    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        println "Entering propertyMissing for name = $name"
        // Create the new data set and add to the map
        def data = new MyPluginDataSet()
        internalMap.put(name, data)

        // setup and execute the client closure to configure the data
        def closure = value as Closure
        closure.delegate = data
        closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        closure.run()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a lot! I'm very newbie in groovy and would never catch this. Just moved the map to an internal property and did end-to-end test. All rolls perfectly.

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to favor composition over inheritance. See Effective Java by Josh Bloch item #16! :)